# Are there drivers for Epson BX625FWD?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, epson

Are There drivers available for the "Epson Stylus Office BX625FWD" printers for Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

The driver for the Epson Stylus Office BX625FWD is here:

- 64 bits: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-office-tx610fw-series/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-office-tx610fw-series_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
- 32 bits: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-office-tx610fw-series/binary-i386/epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-office-tx610fw-series_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb

The new repository for Automatic Printer Driver Download Service of Epson is this:

```
 deb http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/ lsb3.2 main
```

Good luck.